# Removing portions of text file lines?

Tags: python

I have to modify a text file so that the '1900-01-01' at the beginning of each line is gone but the timestamp (00:05:08.627012) remains.

I have tried some line.strip or replace functions but I can't stop running into errors (am brand new at coding)

The text that needs to be changed:

```
1900-01-01 00:05:08.627012 ; 0 ; 1.16198 ; 10000000.0
1900-01-01 00:05:08.627012 ; 1 ; 1.16232 ; 10000000.0
```

The code I am using:

```
for line in lines:
    replace = line.replace('1900-01-01','')
    replace = float(replace)
    ColumnValues.append(replace)
    print(ColumnValues)
```

I need to get the lines to read "00:05:08.627012 ; 0 ; 1.16198 ; 10000000.0" and drop the "1900-01-01" at the beginning but I keep getting the cannot convert string to float error message. Help is appreciated!

Comment: can you confirm that your file has the format as it is in the question? Can you also provide how you are opening your file?

Comment: Are you sure the error appears during replace? Your `replace` call may work just fine and the error happens during `float(replace)`.

Answer (score 0):

`00:05:08.627012 ; 0 ; 1.16198 ; 10000000.0` is not a valid float, so the conversion fails.

If the format is always the same, you can simply slice off the start of the string:

```
for line in lines:
    new_line = line[11:] # slice off the first 11 characters
    ColumnValues.append(new_line)
```

If you want only the inner timestamp:

```
for line in lines:
    new_line = line[11:26] # slice off the first 11 characters, and everything after the 26'th
    ColumnValues.append(new_line)
```

This assumes the format is always the same and takes the same width